# Apache CXF and tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, cxf

I am fairly new to Apache CXF and tomcat. I am trying to build a simple web service and deploy it on tomcat. below is my web.xml
However when I try to access the 'services' folder using my browser it says No services have been found. I tried creating java web service client but it is not able to locate the service either. What could be wrong in this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Sample web service provider</display-name>
    <listener>
        <!-- For Metro, use this listener-class instead: 
             com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener -->
        <listener-class>
              org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Remove below context-param element if using Metro -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
              classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WebServicePort</servlet-name>
        <!-- For Metro, use this servlet-class instead: 
             com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet  -->
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WebServicePort</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 7):

This means that you don't have any services exposed in your application. Your `web.xml` seems to be correct but I've just missed one thing, your Spring configuration. Add your Spring config location in your `web.xml`, for e.g.:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Also, you have to create a class which will implement your web service interface and expose it as the CXF endpoint in your Spring `applicationContext.xml` configuration file. For e.g.:

```
<bean id="candidateImpl" class="some.pckg.CandidateImpl"/>

<jaxws:endpoint id="candidateEndpoint"
                implementor="#candidateImpl"
                address="/Candidate"
        />
```

Your `CandidateImpl` class should have [@WebService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jws/WebService.html) annotation. For e.g.:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://something.com/ws/candidate",
        portName = "CandidateService",
        serviceName = "Candidate",
        endpointInterface = "some.pckg.types.CandidateService",
        wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/CandidateService.wsdl")
public class CandidateImpl implements CandidateService {
     //Implementation of all methods from CandidateService.
}
```

If you've done everything correctly you should see that there is one service available under:

```
http(s)://whateverhost.com:<somePort>/SomeContextPath/services
```

And you should be able to get the WSDL file like this:

```
http(s)://whateverhost.com:<somePort>/SomeContextPath/services/Candidate?wsdl
```

**See also:**

- [Writing a Web Service with Spring](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the spring configuration file location to make this work. You can set it as follows.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a servlet in your web.xml. Below an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
       PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
       "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
       <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
       <servlet-class>
           org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
       </servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>config-location</param-name>
           <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Now you need to define a file named spring-ws-servlet.xml under WEB-INF folder. Below an example of the content of spring-ws-servlet.xml, which contains the actual configuration for your web service. This depends on your logic, of course:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.service"/>

   <!-- JAX-WS Service Endpoint -->
   <bean id="personImpl" class="com.sample.service.impl.PersonServiceImpl"/>

   <jaxws:endpoint id="personEndpoint"
                   implementor="#personImpl"
                   address="/person">
       <jaxws:properties>
           <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true"/>
       </jaxws:properties>
   </jaxws:endpoint>
   <!-- JAX-WS Service Endpoint End-->
</beans>
```

With this, you can access your web service under http://localhost:8080/services/person?wsdl

This is taken from this post. It is a tutorial about creating a Cxf service with IntelliJ Idea and Spring

https://aldavblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/creating-a-web-service-from-scratch-using-spring-maven-apache-cxf/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer with the missing information. Hope it helps.